# call to external API is getting blocked on Google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to connect to an external API from .net.
It is working as expected from other machines.
But we are not getting any respond from the API call when trying from the server.
We have tried accessing the api url on the browser and it failed with the same no response error.

This is what we have done so far.

1. We have checked VPC firewall and tried some firewall rules ( Google Cloud firewall)  and made sure that there is no blocking to this API.
2. We have checked Windows firewall and it is switched off now. We also made sure that there is no rules to block this API. However to test it further, we are now switched it off.
3. Checked that we are able to connect to other websites from the server.
4. Checked whether we can access the API from other machines. We are able to connect to the API successfully using the tokens from the server.
5. We have also installed Wireshark to analyze the incoming and outgoing packets from the server. From this analysis, we were able to find that there are network packets sending to this API and it is trying the retransmits the packets, but there is no acknowledgement packet received. This might be of the below two scenarios.

   1. The acknowledgement packet sent from the API server lost in transition.
   2. The data that we have sent from the server to the API lost in transition.
6. Contacted the API technical team and made sure that the IP is not getting blocked on their end.

Tried contacting Google Support but we have not received much help from them as ours are in "Bronze plan"

This was working without any issues from the server in the past. Not sure what is happening now.

Thank you in advance for all the helps.

Comment: To help diagnose the issue, run the tracert tool and post the results here.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey for your kind reply. We were able to identify the issue from the wireshark analysis. It was the API provider who was blocking the IP. We have contacted them again with the results and they confirmed this. Thank you very much. I will close down this request now.

Comment: Can you make your comment an answer so that we can consider this post closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jeffrey and Patrick for your kind reply. As suggested by Patrick, I am adding here my comments as an answer to close this post. We were able to identify the issue from the wireshark analysis. It was the API provider who was blocking the IP. We have contacted them again with the results and they confirmed this. Thank you very much.